# Can you change a immutable class?

Tags: java, oop, arraylist, immutability

This is a theoretical question for practice.

The question is

> Create an immutable class `Car`.
>
> Create some instances of car to fill an `Arraylist<Car>` inside a `Garage` class.
>
> The `MyGarage` class implements these methods from `Garage`:
>
> - `getCar(String reg)` – search for the car with registration number `reg`.
> - `getMake(String make)` – returns a list of cars that match the given `make`.
> - `totalValue()` – calculates the total value of all cars in the list.
> - `changeOwner(String reg, String ow)` – change the owner of car that has registration number `reg` to `ow`.

I do  not understand the `changeOwner` method as it is not suppose to be able to change a instances of a immutable class I thought???

This is what I have done to work around it but just seems silly

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyGarage implements Garage {
    
    private ArrayList<Car> myGarage;
    
    public MyGarage() {
        myGarage = new ArrayList<Car>();
    }

    @Override
    //Adds a Car if the registration is unique 
    public boolean add(Car c) {
        for(Car car : myGarage) {
            if(car.getRegistration().equals(c.getRegistration())) {                         
                System.out.println("Car has the same Registration as another illegal");
                return false;       
            }   
        }
        myGarage.add(new Car(c.getOwner(),c.getRegistration(),c.getMake(),c.getkilometres(), c.getprice()));
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Car getCar(String carID) {
        for(Car car : myGarage) {
            if(carID.equals(car.getRegistration())) {
                System.out.println("Car Found");
                return car;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("No car of that record");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public ArrayList<Car> getMake(String make) {
        
        ArrayList<Car> carModel = new ArrayList<Car>();
            for(Car car : myGarage) {
                if (car.getMake().equals(make)) {
                    carModel.add(car);
                }           
            }
        System.out.println(carModel.toString());        
        return carModel;
    }

    @Override
    public  void totalValue() {
        double amount = 0;
        for(Car car : myGarage) {
            amount = car.getprice() + amount;
        }
        System.out.println("The total amount is: " + amount);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean changeOwner(String registration, String ow) {

        for(Car car : myGarage) {
            if(car.getRegistration().equals(registration)) {
                myGarage.remove(car);
                car = new Car(ow, "444","F-50",  4, 4000.99);
                myGarage.add(car);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: `car = new Car(ow, "444","F-50",  4, 4000.99);` - `new` means **new** - your are not changing the existing `Car` you are building a new one.

Comment: `myGarage.remove(car);` - does this work?

Comment: @ScaryWombat The OP said they had to workaround immutability. Creating a new `Car` is the workaround, but it doesn't really *change* a car's owner--thus the question.

Comment: Based on the requirements you gave, it seems that cars must not have an owner property. Perhaps you are meant to store owner information in the garage instead of the car.

Comment: @ John Kugelman supports Monica: So do you think what I have done is correct given the question(Even though I have created a new Object)? The car class is supposed to have a owner double checked just now?

Comment: Immutable classes will often have setters that return a cloned object with the field in question updated. In this case that’s hidden within the Garage class, although I’d still implement it this way—you shouldn’t be hard-coding the other values, though; they should be pulled from the immutable instance being updated—and the responsibility for the cloning/etc doesn’t lie with the Garage, rather the Car.

Comment: Expanding on Dave Newton's comment, to see example of this, see the "setter" methods in the Java Time API classes. They are named `withXxx`, see e.g. the [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#i66) methods. In your case, the extra `Car` method would be `Car withOwner(String ow)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In object-oriented and functional programming, an immutable object
>   (unchangeable object) is an object whose state cannot be modified
>   after it is created. This is in contrast to a mutable object
>   (changeable object), which can be modified after it is created. In
>   some cases, an object is considered immutable even if some internally
>   used attributes change, but the object's state appears unchanging from
>   an external point of view. - [WikiPedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object)

Immutable objects are thus instances whose state doesn’t change after they have been initialized. These types of classes are generally good for applications that need to implement some form of caching and where you are worried about thread-safety in a multi-threaded environment (immutable objects are inherently thread-safe).

I don't see your `Car` class, but assuming it'll look something like this:

```
public final class Car { 

  final String registration; 
  final String owner; 

  public Car(String registration, String owner) { 
    this.registration = registration; 
    this.owner= owner; 
  } 

  public String getRegistration() { 
    return registration; 
  } 

  public String getOwner() { 
    return owner; 
  } 
}
```

... notice that there are no `setter` methods in this class. Hence a `car` can only be initialized (i.e `Car myCar = new Car("abcd", "John");` and the variables in them (namely, `registration` and `owner`) can never be updated.

So your `changeOwner` method is essentially looping through the instances of `car` in your `garage` and when it finds a matching registration number it removes that instance of `car` from your `garage` and then adds a whole new one.

To demonstrate this, you can run the following:

```
public class Garage {

  public static void main(String ... args) {
    List<Car> myGarage = new ArrayList<>();
    myGarage.add(new Car("CG404GH", "John"));
    System.out.println(myGarage);
    for(Car car : myGarage) {
        if("CG404GH".equals(car.getRegistration())) {
            myGarage.remove(car);
            Car updateCar = new Car("DD404GH", "John");
            myGarage.add(updateCar);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(myGarage);
  }

}
```

This would print out something similar to the following (the portion after the @ would be different on each run):

```
[Car@4411d970]
[Car@6442b0a6]
```

The important thing to notice here is that the value after the @ are different, hence they are two completely different classes (instances) of `car`